# Is possible to set min and max zoom in Time series Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hello I'm working at **Time series, zoomable** charts of highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

Is it possible to set minimum and maximum zoom ratio?

This is the data of x-axis:

```
data: [
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,6),0.7549],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,7),0.7562],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,9),0.7574],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,10),0.7543],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,11),0.7510],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,12),0.7498],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,13),0.7477],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,14),0.7492],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,16),0.7487],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,17),0.7480],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,18),0.7466],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,19),0.7521],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,20),0.7564]
]
```

I would like that when open the page the interval between **data is weekly**,
when the zoom is at maximum, the interval is **daily** and when zoom is at minimum the interval is **monthly**.

I enabled scrollbar for x-axis.

Is it possible? There's a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the highcharts you can set [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange) parameter which define maximum zoom level.

You can also catch [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) event and calculate range which you need to have on xAxis. Next step is call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.setExtremes) with new range. Obviosuly take care about any flag to avoid infitity loop.